# Bokeh Blur - weak shape

Tags: compositing-nodes, blur

*Bokeh Blur* node creates much weaker shape than *Defocus* node. I'd like to use Blur node due to custom animated bokeh image, but currently I am not happy with simple pentagonal shape.

Left is *Bokeh Blur*, right - *Defocus*

[image]

Increasing size doesn't help...

Comment: Yes I am finding the same thing, I tried adding as multiply math node to the size using a mask as the falloff shape but to mo added benefit. In fact it seems that the final shape is a box blur, or square.